# How to add like dislike image on cards while swapping cards Koloda , swift

Tags: swift, xcode, koloda

I am using [Koloda](https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda) for tinder like application. I successfully created by cards with given example:-

```
func kolodaNumberOfCards(_ koloda:KolodaView) -> Int {
    return 6
}

func kolodaSpeedThatCardShouldDrag(_ koloda: KolodaView) -> DragSpeed {
    return .default
}

func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAt index: Int) -> UIView {

    let view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "home"))
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        view.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return view
}
```

But unable to add like or dislike image on the view. When user swipe left or right i want to add like or dislike image over view. I searched but unable to get the ans. Kindly help me out.

Comment: There are plenty of delegate methods for the `KolodaView`, implement them and call "dislike/like" when needed.

Comment: @Larme thanks for reply , i know thety have overylayview too, but unable to add, can you help me out.